# Primefaces datatable filtering not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to make a table filter using Primefaces 5, 
but the filtering dosn't occur and get the follow stack:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.FilterFeature.filter(FilterFeature.java:136)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.FilterFeature.encode(FilterFeature.java:105)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:77)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:559)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
>     at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:692)   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)    at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:399)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:319)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1896)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:425)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at com.star.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:42)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I'm cloning the primefaces showcase [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml) but i'm not getting it right!

here is my code: 
xhtml file:

```
<p:dataTable id="tbl" var="sim" value="#{simulationLog.simulation}"
                     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                     paginator="true" rows="10" style="margin-bottom:20px"
                     filteredValue="#{simulationLog.filtredSimulation}"
                     >
            <p:column filterBy="#{sim.simId}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Id" />
                </f:facet>
                <p:commandLink value="#{sim.simId}" />
            </p:column>
```

backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SimulationLog implements Serializable {
    .
    .
    .
    private List<SimulationLog> simulation;
    private List<SimulationLog> filtredSimulation;

    public List<SimulationLog> getSimulation() {
        return ParamsDAO.getSimulation(codeAgence);
    }

    public List<SimulationLog> getFiltredSimulation() {
        return filtredSimulation;
    }

    public void setFiltredSimulation(List<SimulationLog> filtredSimulation) {
        this.filtredSimulation = filtredSimulation;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: i downloaded the version 5.0 from the "Community Downloads" table in the primefaces download page.

Comment: no no, i dont, the (. . .) are just some setters and getters for other attributes

Comment: i've added the init method with @PostConstruct, but did'nt work either, same error

Comment: Maybe rowKey="#{sim.simId}" could help. Are you sure the simId values are not null?

Comment: Which type of value `simId` is? Just debug its getter method and check it's being properly recovered by the table.

Comment: it's int, i'm doing everything from scratch now, and i guess the problem is having the List type to the same class, so i made 2 classes Simulation and SimulationLog, and put `private List<Simulation> simulation;` inside `SimulationLog` .. so far so good, its sorting the Sim ID

Comment: @yassine_hell - `filtredSimulation` doesn't appear to be initialized at any point in your code. Are you initializing it?

Comment: @kolossus in the primefaces showcase they aren't initializing it either

Comment: Did you figure it out?, i have the same problem

Comment: well i just made a p:button, that sends u to a servlet page with the id on the url (the p:button has a href attribute)

Answer (score 12):

I had the same error and could fix it by wrapping the dataTable with a `<h:form>`.

Comment: This saved me quite a bit of time, this was driving me crazy!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In short, I had the following and was causing the same error:

```
<f:facet name="header">Date</f:facet>
<f:facet name="filter">
<h:outputText value="Year: " />
<p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('myTable').filter();">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="All" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.conditionalYears}" var="yearSelect" itemValue="#{yearSelect.value}" itemLabel="#{yearSelect.label}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
</f:facet>
```

I had to remove everything from `<f:facet name="filter" />` except the `<p:selectOneMenu />`

In my case, the `<h:outputText />` (not limited to outputText) was causing `ClassCastException` in *FilterFeature:277* that were swallowed by `UIData.visitTree(VisitContext, VisitCallback)` (doesn't have CATCH)

```
filterValue = ((ValueHolder) filterFacet).getLocalValue();
```

For some reason, `filterFacet` is an `UIPanel`, not a `SelectOneMenu` as expected.

**So, the answer is:**
If you are using `<f:facet name="filter" />`, then try removing everything from it except your custom filter field.